# Synology: can log in via ssh as admin, but not root

Tags: ssh, nas, synology, synology-diskstation

Synology DS1513+, DSM 6.2.4-25556 Update 5

I can log into admin via HTTP (and see a GUI desktop) or via SSH (and get a command prompt).

Trying to log in via SSH as root, or from admin, `su` as root, though asks for a password and doesn't accept the admin account password.

Is there even a root account?  If so how can I reset its password without being able to log into root?  In other words does admin have that ability, or can I do it by resetting the disk or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found at https://kb.synology.com/en-id/DSM/tutorial/How_to_login_to_DSM_with_root_permission_via_SSH_Telnet

For my Windows 7, and myDSM >6, the solution is `sudo -i` followed by admin password.

Answer (score 3):

For a real root login (e.g. via WinSCP and SCP protocol) on DSM 6.x/7.x two steps are required:

- Set/Change PW for root (if root PW is not set or not known):
  synouser -setpw root
- Change SSH configuration: The file /etc/ssh/sshd_config needs to contain a line
  PermitRootLogin yes
  (Normally there is the line #PermitRootLogin prohibit-password)
  Restart of at least the SSH deamon required to take effect.
  For both changes you need to login to SSH first with an admin account and use sudo!
  Found in https://think.unblog.ch/synology-root-login-aktivieren/ and https://www.dennis-henss.de/2017/11/07/synology-diskstation214-root-passwort-aendern

Comment: ausgeseichnet, danke!